# Why post.post in my model isnt being displayed in html? (Post)

Tags: python, django

Hi I am trying to display {{post.post}} in html, it worked previously but now it doesn't. The name of the user and date show, and the post is working.. but no success in displaying post.post. Wheres the problem? I've displayed the output below and highlighted something that could give an indication. TIA

html:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block body%}
<div class="container">
    <h1>Home</h1>
    <form method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
<h2>{{ text }}</h2>
{% for post in posts %}
    <h1>{{ post.post }}</h1>
    <p>Posted by <b>{{ post.user.get_full_name}}</b> on {{ post.date }}</p>
{% endfor %}
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

models.py:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    post = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

views.py:

```
class HomeView(TemplateView):
   template_name = ('home/home.html')

   def get(self, request):
     form = HomeForm()
     posts = Post.objects.all()

     args = {'form': form, 'posts': posts}
     return render(request, self.template_name, args)

   def post(self, request):
     form = HomeForm(request.POST)
     if form.is_valid():
        post = form.save(commit=False)
        post.user = request.user
        post.save()
        text = form.cleaned_data['Post']
        form = HomeForm()
        return redirect('home:home')

     args = {'form': form, 'text': text}
     return render(request, self.template_name, args)
```

output:

```
hfdhdth
Posted by john wick on Oct. 11, 2018, 6:56 p.m.
vdfgrgrtg
Posted by john wick on Oct. 11, 2018, 6:56 p.m.
'btgthh' <------AFTER THIS DOESNT DISPLAY
Posted by john wick on Oct. 11, 2018, 6:56 p.m.

Posted by john wick on Oct. 11, 2018, 7:13 p.m.

Posted by john wick on Oct. 11, 2018, 7:13 p.m.

Posted by john wick on Oct. 11, 2018, 7:13 p.m.
```

Comment: is this in the get request or post request?

Comment: I don't know its in post request I think

Answer (score 0):

You aren't including the `posts` in the context data for the post request when the form isn't valid, you simply just need to add this to the context

```
args = {'form': form, 'text': text}
```

to

```
args = {'form': form, 'text': text, 'posts': Post.objects.all()}
```

Comment: this didn't fix it

Comment: @JosephS - Then your problem isn't anything to do with your code shown here. Most likely, those other posts just don't contain any text, Try doing `Post.objects.values_list('post', flat=True)` in a terminal or just output somewhere

Comment: did that ...NameError: name 'Post' is not defined

Comment: @JosephS - Yes you'd need to import it.. just include it in the context of your get request if thats easier.

Comment: In [3]: Post.objects.values_list('post', flat=True)
Out[3]: <QuerySet ['hfdhdth', 'vdfgrgrtg', 'btgthh', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '...(remaining elements truncated)...']>

Comment: @JosephS - Right, so you have a load of posts without any text in the post

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181699/discussion-between-josephs-and-sayse).

Comment: I see but I write text in the field? sorry don't want to turn this into a chat for guidelines sake

Comment: @JosephS - That may be but you're db still contains lots of posts you've made erroneously, `Post.objects.exclude(post="").values_list('post', flat=True)`, might help you to visualise this better but basically your problem is with the data, not the code

Comment: really weird...im going to take a break but thanks for the help. I got this after I typed that code in terminal:
In [2]: Post.objects.exclude(post="").values_list('post', flat=True)
Out[2]: <QuerySet ['hfdhdth', 'vdfgrgrtg', 'btgthh']>
really weird seemed like it just bugged out

Comment: managed to fix it 
views.py: text=form.cleaned_data['post']

forms.py: post=forms.Charfield()